# How to get Not Distinct Values and display data

Tags: mysql, sql

Example Table

## Select LastName, FirstName From Table;

---

```
| LastName   |   Firstname|
|            |            |
| Dela Cruz  |    Juan    |
| Dela Cruz  |    John    |
| Simon      |    Lucy    |
| Stin       |    Joy     |
```

## How Can I Query this output, Or View Data with Non Distinct Values:

```
| LastName   |   Firstname|
|            |            |
| Dela Cruz  |    Juan    |
| Dela Cruz  |    John    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.`LastName` AS LName
     , m.`FirstName` AS FName
     , m.`MiddleName` AS MName
FROM table m JOIN ( SELECT `LastName`
                    FROM `table` 
                    GROUP BY `LastName`
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) x ON x.`LastName` = m.`LastName`
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e560d5/1)

Comment: I want to get or show the values not the total count.

Comment: @user3736185 : It will display all duplicate rows for all `Last name`s

Comment: @user3736185 : it is an alias for the `table`.See the example.What is the exact error?

Comment: Can I have one last question, Actually there is 4 column in my table, I want To Select 3 of them. example LastName as LName, FirstName as FName, MiddleName as MName. And My last column is age which I will not include to display. Thanks That my last problem thanks.